# How can I block search engine indexing of files and subdirectories other than root directory .php and .html files without listing the directory names?

Tags: security, seo, robots.txt

I would like to make it so that search engines only index .html and .php files in my sites root directory and no sub directories. I want to do this without actually listing the explicitly directory names in the robots.txt file so it's not easy for hackers and malicious people to easily find my secret and important directories. So for example:

```
Index:
domainname.com/index.php
domainname.com/index.html
domainname.com
domainname.com/
```

> Don't Index:
>
> domainname.com/randomdirectory/*
>
> domainname.com/index.htmldfgdfgg
>
> domainname.com/randomfile.example
>
> domainname.com/index.phpffgfdfgdf

Here's my code so far (I'm definitely no expert on robots.txt):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: //*$
Disallow: /*$
Allow: /*.php$
Allow: /*.html$
Allow: /$
Allow: $
Disallow: /*/*
```

Comment: @JohnConde thanks for your concern, but this question is 100% on topic. In this question I'm not talking about page ranking, Google "liking" anything, etc. I am talking about writing code in robots.txt file to solve a problem, which is programming related and does follow the rules for Stack Overflow. Here's a quote from the article you sent that sums this up: "To put it another way, as long as your question is about programming, it's on-topic, even with the SEO tag.". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.example$

i.e.

Disallow: /*.extenstion$

Comment: Thanks, but I would have to list out all the explicit directories I want to keep hidden for this. I did figure it out though, thanks  anyway :)